# Hardware back button in WP8.1 universal app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

The question is about a windows phone 8.1 universal app, not the blank app template but other templates which have
the NavigationHelper class in Common folder.
Is it possible to navigate from a certain page regardless of the navigation history to a certain page using
the hardware back button?
for example if the navigation goes from page1 to page2 > page3 > page2 and page3 then the navigation back with the 
hardware back button will be from page3 to page2 > page3 > page2 and page1. is it possible to manage programaticaly so 
that the Hardware back button ALWAYS navigates back from page2 to page1 regardless of the navigation history? 
Because, hardware back button navigates through all pages and in this case it will navigate to page3 then page2 and 
finally page1. What I am trying to achieve here is that when the user uses Hardware back button on page2 I want to 
get the user ALWAYS to page1. I just used AppBarButtons for page navigation with the following code:

```
Frame.Navigate(typeof(Page2));
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: In WP8.1 you can surely put your own logic under back button, you can navigate, manage back stack or other, so it should be possible to do what you want. You will find many questions on SO dealing with back button, which may help you.

Comment: @Romasz I am really sorry to ask this but what is SO?

Comment: This is SO...you're on SO. SO = Stack Overflow

Comment: Thank you very much it was really a silly question for a moment my mind was not working!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In WP, you must avoid circular navigation, so you shouldn't go from page3 to page2, try a

```
Frame.GoBack();
```

to go back to page2 after page3

Or, you can manage manually by overriding the BackPressed event, check the type of current page, do what you want and set

```
this.handled = true
```

More info : http://grogansoft.com/blog/?p=577